# path.exists() function does'nt work properly in for different directories in python IDE-PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, path

The path object of 'module' directory returns True but the path object of 'kick_start'(and also all other directories too) returns False,
allthough both of them belong to the same super directory i.e. python_Jan 2020.[click here for the link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw2ps.png)

Comment: relative path are resolved against the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), not against the path of the current python script or module.